# Process large DataTable using data from another in R

Tags: r, data.table, tidyverse

I need to process a large data.table, setting a value in one column where there is a match between two other columns and another separate (small) Search Terms data.table. The value of the column is taken from the Search Terms where a match is found.

A match is found specifically where:

- a field (status in the example code) in the main DT matches a str_detect pattern in the Search Terms DT (searchStatus)
- if specified for the above str_detect pattern, the date from main DT must be within the Search Term specified date range (from and to)

I have simplified my use case in the code below which uses the default storms data set (10k records). The main DT has 6.5 million records and the search term DT has less than 200.

My two questions are:

1. is there a way to make this more efficient (and reduce the estimated
   90 minutes elapsed it will take to process 6.5 million record in the
   large data table?
2. how I can obtain a data.table result instead of the matrix which has
   been transposed (with columns as rows and rows as columns)?

Many thanks.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)

data("storms")
setDT(storms)
storms <- storms %>% 
  mutate(date = paste(year, month, day, sep="-") %>% ymd() %>% as.Date())

# Create simple Search Term Data Table
searchStatus = c("hurricane", "orm", "sion")
replacementStatus = c("hurricane any time", "76 storm", "81 depression")
from = c("", "1976-01-01", "1976-01-01") 
to = c("", "1981-01-01", "1981-12-31")
searchTerms = data.frame(searchStatus, replacementStatus, from, to) 
setDT(searchTerms)

# Function to determine if any search terms apply to the given row
# Typically only one is expected, although not guaranteed, so the first is taken
# A replacedStatus field is added containing either
# - the parameterised replacementStatus where a matching search term has been identified
# - the original status where no match has been identified 
recodeValues <- function(row) { 
  date = row["date"]
  status = row["status"]
  recodeMatch <- head(
    searchTerms[str_detect(status, searchTerms$searchStatus) &
                  (searchTerms$from == "" | date >= as.Date(searchTerms$from)) &
                  (searchTerms$to == ""   | date <= as.Date(searchTerms$to))
                  ,]
      ,1)
  # I would use mult = "first" in the selection above but it seem to have no impact, so use head() instead
  row["replacedStatus"]  <- if_else(nrow(recodeMatch) > 0, recodeMatch[1]$replacementStatus, status)
  return(row)
}

cat("Starting Recoding", "\n")
processorTime <- proc.time()
result <- apply(storms, 1, recodeValues)
cat("Recoding time (Elapsed):", proc.time()[3] - processorTime[3], " seconds \n")
cat("Estimated Recoding time (Elapsed) for 6.5m records:", (proc.time()[3] - processorTime[3]) * 6500000 / nrow(storms) / 60, " minutes \n")
View(result)
```

Comment: I’m not entirely sure what you mean, but it finds the first match and uses that to determine the setting of the new field, replacedStatus. Apart from the transposed matrix formatting, it does actually work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want it might make more sense to iterate over the small "searchTerms" `data.table` than over the large "storms" one.

You could then do something like this, which better leverages the power of `data.table`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)
data("storms")
setDT(storms)
storms <- storms %>% 
    mutate(date = paste(year, month, day, sep="-") %>% ymd() %>% as.Date())

# Create simple Search Term Data Table
searchStatus = c("hurricane", "orm", "sion")
replacementStatus = c("hurricane any time", "76 storm", "81 depression")
from = c("", "1976-01-01", "1976-01-01") 
to = c("", "1981-01-01", "1981-12-31")
searchTerms = data.frame(searchStatus, replacementStatus, from, to) 
setDT(searchTerms)

cat("Starting Recoding", "\n")
#> Starting Recoding
processorTime <- proc.time()
for(i in seq_len(dim(searchTerms)[1])){
    x <- as.list(searchTerms[i])
    if(x$from == "") {
        storms[grep(x$searchStatus, status),
               status:= x$replacementStatus]  
    } else {
        storms[grep(x$searchStatus, status) &
                   between(date, as.Date(x$from), as.Date(x$to)),
               status:= x$replacementStatus]
    }
}

cat("Recoding time (Elapsed):", proc.time()[3] - processorTime[3], " seconds \n")
#> Recoding time (Elapsed): 0.034  seconds
cat("Estimated Recoding time (Elapsed) for 6.5m records:", (proc.time()[3] - processorTime[3]) * 6500000 / nrow(storms) / 60, " minutes \n")
#> Estimated Recoding time (Elapsed) for 6.5m records: 0.3787879  minutes
tail(storms[])
#>    name year month day hour  lat  long             status category wind
#> 1: Kate 2015    11  10   12 29.5 -75.4     tropical storm        0   60
#> 2: Kate 2015    11  10   18 31.2 -74.0     tropical storm        0   60
#> 3: Kate 2015    11  11    0 33.1 -71.3 hurricane any time        1   65
#> 4: Kate 2015    11  11    6 35.2 -67.6 hurricane any time        1   70
#> 5: Kate 2015    11  11   12 36.2 -62.5 hurricane any time        1   75
#> 6: Kate 2015    11  11   18 37.6 -58.2 hurricane any time        1   65
#>    pressure ts_diameter hu_diameter       date
#> 1:      998    103.5702      0.0000 2015-11-10
#> 2:      993    103.5702      0.0000 2015-11-10
#> 3:      990    161.1092     23.0156 2015-11-11
#> 4:      985    207.1404     23.0156 2015-11-11
#> 5:      980    345.2340     34.5234 2015-11-11
#> 6:      980    379.7574     46.0312 2015-11-11
```

Comment: Hi @user12728748, this is a great answer.  I can see that the loop is on the small table (so the relative inefficiency has no real impact) and that the large table is handled using data.table's highly efficient search capabilities.  As a result, the run time is now 1/240th of the original, so processing my 6.5 million records will be really quick.  Not only a solution to this problem but also learning for me and others for other requirements.  Thank you.